# How to fix when Fedora 26 installation undetected/unlisted on Ubuntu-grub menu

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub

I installed Fedora(32-bit) for 1st time. I tried to set my dual-booted(Windows 7 & Ubuntu 14.04) BIOS-PC to triple-boot with Fedora 26 without fruit.

I started as below...

1. Created 3 standard partitions instead of LVM partition:

   - `/` - encrypted,ext4, 10 GB.
   - `/boot` - unencrypted,ext4.
   - `swap` - unencrypted.
2. I unchecked 'bootloader install' from Anaconda since there was already ubuntu-grub on MBR. At the end Installer says it successfully installed fedora. but after reboot, Fedora 26 was not listed on GRUB 2 boot menu. I ran `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu terminal but result was unchanged. I can see those newly created partitions using `sudo blkid`.

   Here is the output of `sudo blkid`:

   ```
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="F2622FA6622F6F13" TYPE="ntfs"
   /dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="FE703488703449A3" TYPE="ntfs"
   /dev/sda5: UUID="03f69c95-69fd-4302-adf3-96a495584a4c" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/sda6: UUID="9087cac3-ee43-4c6b-9cf3-bf818697e239" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/sda7: LABEL="Common Drive" UUID="EA203DE0203DB483" TYPE="ntfs"
   /dev/sda8: UUID="1b498ed0-dd4c-4021-942f-4c20ba4bb79c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
   /dev/sda9: LABEL="Fd-bt" UUID="720dc2b9-e1fe-4adc-a2de-10c26567729a" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/sda10: LABEL="Fd-swp" UUID="d8b3cdd6-908f-4a5d-8ac5-9ec1dfb62fa6" TYPE="swap"
   ```

Here, `sda8` is the Fedora root partition.

My question is how to fix or overcome this problem?  Do I have to install some additional package for encrypted `sda8` or something else?

Comment: Your initrd in `/dev/sda9` should have what's necessary to unlock the LUKS container and proceed booting from there. The problem is GRUB doesn't know about your Fedora installation. Do you have a grub2 configuration in  `/dev/sda9`? This would be a separate config from the grub installed from Ubuntu.

Comment: This happened _because_ you chose not to install the bootloader. Try booting Ubuntu and running grub-install again.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa No, grub2 not configured on /dev/sda9. can you tell me the steps to do that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, but there was already grub2 of ubuntu

Comment: so, I am asking you both, what is the solution of it?

Comment: Guys plz response if you have answers.

Comment: I already gave you a response! You did not try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 26 uses Anaconda as the installer. Anaconda doesn't make a distinction between the two GRUB2 stages when installing the boot loader; You either install GRUB2 completely, or not at all:

> If you choose not to install a boot loader for any reason, you will
>   not be able to boot the system directly, and you must use another boot
>   method, such as a stand-alone commercial boot loader application. *Use
>   this option only if you are sure you have another way to boot your
>   system.* - Source https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f26/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda.html#sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning-bootloader

In short, not installing GRUB2 from Fedora/Anaconda means a world of hurt. Here's your best bet:

1. Reinstall Fedora 26 *with* the boot loader. This is going to sacrifice the GRUB2 stage1 installed by Ubuntu, but Fedora will then boot; Ubuntu will not. Make sure you use a separate boot partition for Fedora, like you've already done.
2. Use GRUB2's ability to load another configuration to create a menu entry which loads Ubuntu's GRUB2 configuration.

In other words, you'd be delegating ownership of the boot process to Fedora.

### Loading the Ubuntu GRUB2 menu from Fedora

Here's approximately how to complete step two:

1. Boot Fedora
2. Mount your `/boot` partition if it's not already mounted: `mount /boot`
3. Update `/etc/fstab` to automatically mount Ubuntu's boot partition:

`mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
echo "/dev/sda5 /mnt/ubuntu ext4 defaults,ro 0 0" >> /etc/fstab`

4. Mount the Ubuntu boot partition: `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt/ubuntu`
5. Create a custom menu entry which simply loads Ubuntu's GRUB2 config. Append the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

`menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'ubuntu-xyz' {
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        configfile /mnt/ubuntu/grub2/grub.cfg
}`

6. Update Fedora's GRUB2 config so that it adds your new menu: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
7. Reboot and cross your finders.

### Warning

This process is a delicate procedure. It's provided as a best-effort solution considering I do not have your computer in front of me. *Don't be surprised if it doesn't work*. Take any necessary backups and proceed with the full acknowledgement that it may go from bad to worse; You may have to wipe the disk and start over.

Comment: thanx. i will try & tell you the results.

Comment: thank God! it worked! @Emmanuel before trying your suggested method, I reinstalled fedora once again as a last resort.but this time, the /dev/sda8 i.e fedora-root partition without any encryption and mounted from Ubuntu.then 'sudo update-grub' recognized the root. last time /dev/sda8 could not be mounted, I dont know why. Default 'seahorse' was unable to mount it. may be I should have installed some crypto-package. may be, there is a bug on fedora side. power users can explain the cause better.
however, thanks to all members & moderators especially Emmanuel & Michael for their inputs.
Bye!

Comment: 1 question remains, how to install is case of LUKS-encrypted root partition?

Comment: Anaconda knows how to handle an encrypted root partition; It ensures there's a separate /boot partition which is not encrypted. The Linux kernel and the initrd ramdisk are stored in the unencrypted /boot partition so the boot loader can access it. It's the initrd that's responsible for (among other things) prompting for the LUKS password and unlocking the root partition.